# Как преобразовать dataset для нейросети

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Вопрос в следующем: для тренировок обучения нейросети в `ScLearn` есть `dataset Iris`. У меня есть рабочая нейросеть для тренировок с ирисами, которая мне подходит для решения другой задачи. Но для её решения - никак не могу преобразовать свою выборку из `.csv` или `.xlsx` в тот формат, который получается из реального `dataset`:

```
from sklearn import datasets  
iris = datasets.load_iris()
dataset = [(iris.data[i][None,...], iris.target[i]) for i in range(len(iris.target))]
print(dataset)
```

Мне из `.csv` или `.xlsx` нужно получить именно такой формат, так как все мои варианты не подошли для дальнейшего использования, основной код не мой, да и собственно мало времени на создание своего.
Помогите пожалуйста на примере этих же ирисов, если этот датасет сохранить в эксель, то как его потом преобразовать обратно в тот вид, который получается при выгрузке из сети?

Comment: `нужно получить именно такой формат` - какой формат вам нужно получить - такой как в объекте `iris` или такой как в `dataset`?

Comment: такой как dataset

Comment: хммм... зачем из удобной и понятной 2D матрицы `iris.data` размерности `(150, 4)` создавать список кортежей, где  элементами являются матрицы размерности `(1, 4)` ??

Comment: Я прекрасно это понимаю... Но признаюсь честно, у меня очень мало опыта в python. просто мне нужно вместо выборки с ирисами загрузить свою с эксель, а все мои попытки преобразования данных были тщетны. 
Просто в самой нейронке идёт использование batch, в которых я не сильно разобрался... и дальнейшее использование датасет воспринимается именно втаком формате в виде кортежей.
У меня уже крышу сносит, подскажите пожалуйста как с экселя мне сделать такой формат... Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось помучиться, но у меня получись сделать самому... Смотрите:

```
irisDf = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
x = irisDf.drop(columns = ['name','target']).to_numpy().tolist()
y = irisDf['target'].to_numpy().tolist()

dataset = [(np.array([x[i]]), y[i]) for i in range(len(y))]
```

Comment: Всем "соведддчикам" и "профффэсионалам" СпаСыБо

Comment: а где в вашем ответе самому себе вообще использование sklearn, про который упоминаете в вопросе?

Comment: Без обид только... Вы внимательно читали вопрос? Цитирую "У меня есть рабочая нейросеть для тренировок с ирисами, которая мне подходит для решения другой задачи. Но для её решения - никак не могу преобразовать свою выборку из .csv или .xlsx в тот формат, который получается из реального dataset:"
Так вот проблема состояла только лишь в том, чтобы получился такой формат при импорте с экселя, как я указал в коде.
Вы вообще код запускали? :)

Comment: а куда вы первое предложение свое убрали то из цитирования? "Вопрос в следующем: для тренировок обучения нейросети в ScLearn есть dataset Iris."